# Best methodology to prepare 3d models for avatar customization?

Tags: 3d, 3d-meshes

I know preparing mount points and the like. But what's the best way to prevent Z fighting with customizations close to moving parts like elbows and knees?

Comment: What is the platform? OpenGL/DirectX or something else?

Comment: Well this is mostly a general question of how to prepare 3d avatars for customizables most likely clothes like pants and long sleeves as those are the ones that are gonna be affected by animations most of the time due to being near the joints.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some ways to prevent z fighting.

- Make the near and far planes close together and the space between clothing parts as far as possible.
- Depending on the types of animations and the situation it might be possible to disable z testing/writing and rely on painters algorithm.
- Write a screen capture app. Go through your characters and animations and have your artist adjust the animations if there are problems.